Is there such a thing as the "Second Passage Time"?
I am learning about the First Passage Times (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitting_time) of Stochastic Processes - how to derive the Probability Distribution for the time required for a Stochastic Process to first pass a certain point.
In certain cases, there is a well known probability distribution for this problem. For example, in a Brownian Motion with drift, I heard that this probability distribution is an Inverse Gaussian Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution)
This leads me to my question:

Provided a Stochastic Process (e.g. initial conditions, stochastic process) - how would we find out the Probability Distribution of the 2nd Passage Time?  (e.g. Distribution of when the Process $X_t$ will pass the point $x=x_0$ for the second time given that it is currently at $x = x_0$)
Or more generally, how would we find out the nth Passage Time?

Here is my logic: Since a Stochastic Process like the Brownian Motion has independent increments and obeys the Markov Property - after passing a point for the first time, the time needed to pass the same point a second time should be independent. To me, this means I should be able to add the two distributions together (via convolution) to derive this distribution?
For example, consider a Brownian Motion:
$$ X(t) = \mu t + \sigma W(t),$$

The increments $ X(t) - X(s) $ for $ 0 \leq s < t $ are independent of the past values $ X(u) $ for $ u \leq s $.
$ X(t) - X(s) \sim N\left(\mu (t - s), \sigma^2 (t - s)\right).$

From here, I will use the properties of convolutions. Here is the well known convolution formula that allows us to find the probability distribution for the sum of two random variables (provided they are independent):
If $ X $ and $ Y $ are two independent continuous random variables with pdfs $ f_X(x) $ and $ f_Y(y) $, then the pdf of the sum $ Z = X + Y $ is given by the convolution of $ f_X $ and $ f_Y $:
$$ f_Z(z) = (f_X * f_Y)(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z - x) \, dx $$
Now, relating it to the Inverse Gaussian Distribution:
$$
f(x; \mu, \lambda) = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^3}} \exp \left( -\frac{\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2 x} \right)
$$
$$
E[X] = \mu
$$
$$
Var[X] = \frac{{\mu^3}}{{\lambda}}
$$
Given that the first passage time of a Brownian motion to a level $a$ follows an inverse Gaussian distribution, we can apply convolution to find the distribution of the second passage time.
Let:

$ T_a^{(1)} \sim \text{IG}\left( \frac{a}{\mu}, \frac{a^2}{\sigma^2} \right) $ be the first passage time.
$ T_a' \sim \text{IG}\left( \frac{a}{\mu}, \frac{a^2}{\sigma^2} \right) $ be an independent identically distributed random variable representing the next passage time.

I think I can use the convolution formula to determine the pdf for the second passage time $ T_a^{(2)} = T_a^{(1)} + T_a' $,  with the pdf given by the convolution of the pdfs of $ T_a^{(1)} $ and $ T_a' $.
$$
   f_{T_a^{(2)}}(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f_{T_a^{(1)}}(x) f_{T_a'}(t - x) \, dx
 $$
Since $ T_a^{(1)} $ and $ T_a' $ have the same distribution, I think the integral becomes:
$$
   f_{T_a^{(2)}}(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f_{IG}(x; \mu, \lambda) f_{IG}(t - x; \mu, \lambda) \, dx
 $$
While I am not sure how to work with this integral, I am guessing that because of the independence of the two distributions, the Expected Value and Variance can be analyzed as the sum of iid random variables?
$$
  \mathbb{E}[T_a^{(2)}] = 2 \cdot \frac{a}{\mu}
$$
$$
  \text{Var}(T_a^{(2)}) = 2 \cdot \frac{a^2}{\sigma^2 \mu^2}
$$
Is my reasoning correct?
Note: If the above logic/reasoning is correct, I should be able to extend this to higher order passage times (i.e. nth passage time). The $ n $-th passage time $ T_a^{(n)} $ is the sum of $ n $ independent and identically distributed inverse Gaussian random variables:
$$
T_a^{(n)} = T_a^{(1)} + T_a' + \cdots + T_a^{(n-1)}
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[T_a^{(n)}] = n \cdot \frac{a}{\mu}
$$
$$
\text{Var}(T_a^{(n)}) = n \cdot \frac{a^2}{\sigma^2 \mu^2}
$$

My intuition is that if we start at $0$ and the bar $a$ is set extremely high, the 2nd pass will start at this extremely high value $a$, i.e., the 2nd one is "from $a$ to $a$" rather than "from $0$ to $a$".

@ Zach Fisher: thank you for this comment! Would love to read an answer if you have time!

I spent the whole day working on this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4946026/how-long-will-it-take-for-a-coin-to-repeat-a-certain-behavior if you have time can you please take a look? Thank you so much!

It's not in my area of expertise. But if I have to do it, I'll multiply the 2 distributions to obtain the joint distribution (i.e., "marginal of 1st" $\times$ "conditional of 2nd given 1st"). From this joint, we can then obtain the distribution of their sum by way of transformation of variables.

@ Zack Fisher: I tried to write an answer based on your comments ... if I have done everything correctly, it looks like the final answer still stays the same?

Back to 1st comment: I'm not convinced that the 2 times are identically distributed. Independent increment does not justify this.
For discrete time processes, I think it may be possible to derive the 2nd hit time or passage time (if we clarify if it is high->low pass, or low->high pass). The "marginal x conditional" should give the joint.
For the Brownian motion example, I now don't believe the concept of "2nd passage time" making much sense: Once reaching $a$ at time $T$, it will essentially cross the bar a 2nd time, i.e., the 2nd time (beyond the 1st) is $0$.

Based on the comments provided by @Zack Fisher, I tried to write an answer:

Using the Law of Conditional Probability:

If $ X $ and $ Y $ are two random variables, the joint probability density function (pdf) $ f_{X, Y}(x, y) $ can be expressed as:
$$ 
f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_X(x) f_{Y|X}(y|x)
$$
And of course, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent (as they are in this problem), then:
$$ 
f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_X(x) \cdot f_Y(y) 
$$

Going back to the question, we saw that:

The marginal pdf of the first passage time $ T_a^{(1)} $ is:
$$
 f_{T_a}(t_1) = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi t_1^3}} \exp \left( -\frac{\lambda(t_1 - \mu)^2}{2\mu^2 t_1} \right)
 $$
Since $ T_a^{(1)} $ and $ T_a' $ are independent, the conditional pdf $ f_{T_a'|T_a^{(1)}}(t_2|t_1) $ is:
$$
 f_{T_a'|T_a^{(1)}}(t_2|t_1) = f_{T_a}(t_2)
 $$
It follows that for the Joint Distribution:
The joint pdf $ f_{T_a^{(1)}, T_a'}(t_1, t_2) $ is:
$$
 f_{T_a^{(1)}, T_a'}(t_1, t_2) = f_{T_a}(t_1) f_{T_a}(t_2)
 $$

Now, we recall the Change of Variable Rule - this is used to find out the PDF for variable transformations:

If $ X $ is a random variable with pdf $ f_X(x) $ and $ Y = g(X) $ is a new random variable, then the pdf of $ Y $, denoted by $ f_Y(y) $, is given by:
$$
f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) \right|
$$
If $ (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) $ is a vector of random variables with joint pdf $ f_{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) $, and $ (Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n) $ is another vector of random variables defined by the transformation $ \mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{X}) $, then the joint pdf of $ \mathbf{Y} $ is:
$$
f_{\mathbf{Y}}(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n) = f_{\mathbf{X}}(g_1^{-1}(y_1, \ldots, y_n), g_2^{-1}(y_1, \ldots, y_n), \ldots, g_n^{-1}(y_1, \ldots, y_n)) \left| \det \mathbf{J} \right|
$$

The next part was a bit difficult on how to apply the Change of Variable Rule to this problem.

I defined two Random Variables to represent the first and seccond passage times (one is a function of the other)
$$
 U = T_a^{(1)}, \quad V = T_a^{(1)} + T_a'
 $$
I then tried to compute the Jacobian of the transformation:
$$
 J = \begin{vmatrix}
 \frac{\partial U}{\partial t_1} & \frac{\partial U}{\partial t_2} \\
 \frac{\partial V}{\partial t_1} & \frac{\partial V}{\partial t_2}
 \end{vmatrix} =
 \begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1
 \end{vmatrix} = 1
 $$
The joint pdf of $ (U, V) $ is:
$$
 f_{U, V}(u, v) = f_{T_a}(u) f_{T_a}(v - u)
 $$
To find the pdf of $ V $, we integrate out $ U $:
$$
 f_{V}(v) = \int_{0}^{v} f_{U, V}(u, v) \, du = \int_{0}^{v} f_{T_a}(u) f_{T_a}(v - u) \, du
 $$

Conclusion: Even after this integration process, I think the final results will still stay the same due to the properties of expectations and sums of (independent) random variables.

$$
   \mathbb{E}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[T_a^{(1)}] + \mathbb{E}[T_a']
 $$
$$
   \mathbb{E}[T_a^{(1)}] = \mathbb{E}[T_a'] = \mu
 $$
$$
   \mathbb{E}[Z] = \mu + \mu = 2\mu
 $$
$$
   \text{Var}(Z) = \text{Var}(T_a^{(1)}) + \text{Var}(T_a')
 $$
$$
   \text{Var}(T_a^{(1)}) = \text{Var}(T_a') = \frac{\mu^3}{\lambda}
 $$
$$
   \text{Var}(Z) = \frac{\mu^3}{\lambda} + \frac{\mu^3}{\lambda} = 2\frac{\mu^3}{\lambda}
 $$

Generalizing to the nth passage:

$$
   \mathbb{E}[T_a^{(n)}] = n \mathbb{E}[T_a^{(1)}] = n\mu
 $$
$$
   \text{Var}(T_a^{(n)}) = n \text{Var}(T_a^{(1)}) = n \frac{\mu^3}{\lambda}
 $$

I guess we need to think of a discrete model for this idea to work. For Brownian motion, the Wikipedia page describes that, for any $\epsilon>0$, the sample path during $(0,\epsilon)$ takes both positive and negative values. Thus, once reaching $a$ for the first time at time $T$, the sample path during $(T, T+\epsilon)$ will cover both values $>a$ and those $<a$. So, the only meaningful 2nd pass time beyond $T$ is thus $0$.

@ Zack: thank you for the feedback ... if you have time, I would love to read what you have to say...
