How long will it take for a coin to repeat a certain behavior?
I came across the following question:
Part 1: Suppose there is a coin that if heads, then the flip is heads with p=0.99. And if tails, the next flip is tails with p=0.99. If the first flip is random - what is the long term ratio of heads to tails?
At first, this question sounded very obvious. I initially thought that the long term ratio of heads to tails will depend on the first flip - since after the first flip, the coin will have very high probability of repeating itself forever. But then after thinking about this some more, I thought that eventually, when the coin lands on the other side - it will then again start to repeat that behavior for a long time, thus balancing everything out.
To verify this, I made a computer simulation in R, and saw that in the long run - the ratio of heads-tails approaches 0.5:

I then thought - if this true for p=0.99 - the same logic should apply for all values of p between (0 and 1)? I tried to empirically verify this using a computer simulation - and it again seems that the long term behavior tends to 0.5, regardless of the initial value of p:


Part 2: I thought that this problem can be analyzed using and Stationary Distributions and Limiting Distribution.
In the case of the Stationary Distribution, we can see that the long term behavior is (0.5, 0.5):
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
0.99 & 0.01 \\
0.01 & 0.99
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\pi = \begin{pmatrix} \pi_H & \pi_T \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \pi_H & \pi_T \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.99 & 0.01 \\
0.01 & 0.99
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \pi_H & \pi_T \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
0.99 \pi_H + 0.01 \pi_T = \pi_H \\
0.01 \pi_H + 0.99 \pi_T = \pi_T
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\pi = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix}
$$
In the case of the Limiting Distribution, we can also see that the long term behavior is (0.5, 0.5) using matrix diagonalization (D is a matrix of Eigenvalues and S is a matrix of Eigenvectors):
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P^n
$$
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0.99 & 0.01 \\
0.01 & 0.99
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
P = SDS^{-1}
$$
$$
\det(P - \lambda I) = (0.99 - \lambda)^2 - (0.01)^2 = 0
$$
$$
\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 0.98
$$
$$
S = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0.98
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
S^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
P^n = SD^nS^{-1}
$$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} D^n = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P^n = S\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}S^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\pi = [0.5, 0.5]
$$
Furthermore, looking at this Markov Chain - we can see that it is both Irreducible and Aperiodic. Thus, this Markov Chain is Ergodic. in an Ergodic Markov Chain, the Stationary Distribution is equal to the Limiting Distribution.
My Question: Given this information, I am trying to understand the following point: How long (i.e. number of transitions) will it approximately take for this Markov Chain to reach its Stationary and Limiting Distributions?
Reading about this topic, I came across the concept of Mixing Times and Spectral Gaps (e.g https://weitsehsu.com/post/spectral_gap/). I tried to apply this to my problem, but I was not sure how to do this. Here is my attempt:

First, define the Mixing Time ( $P^t(x,·)$ is the distribution after t steps) -  this looking at the absolute distance between the distribution of states at time t vs the stationary distribution, bounded between some epsilon. This absolute distance is also called the "Total Variational Distance":

$$t_{mix}(\varepsilon) = \min\{t : \max_{x \in \Omega} \|P^t(x,\cdot) - \pi\|_{TV} \leq \varepsilon\}$$

Next, define the Spectral Gap ($\lambda_2$ is the second largest eigenvalue of the transition matrix.):

$$\text{spectral gap} = 1 - \lambda_2$$

The next part I did not understand why its true - but assuming its true: For a reversible Markov chain, we can bound this convergence using the spectral gap (π_min is the smallest probability in the stationary distribution):

$$\|P^t(x,\cdot) - \pi\|_{TV} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi_{min}}} \lambda_2^t$$

From here, I tried to follow some of the manipulations:

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi_{min}}} \lambda_2^t \leq \varepsilon$$
$$t \geq \frac{\log(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon\sqrt{\pi_{min}}})}{\log(1/\lambda_2)}$$
$$\log(1/\lambda_2) \approx 1 - \lambda_2$$
$$t \geq \frac{\log(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon\sqrt{\pi_{min}}})}{1 - \lambda_2} = \frac{\log(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon\sqrt{\pi_{min}}})}{\text{spectral gap}}$$
$$t_{mix}(\varepsilon) \leq \frac{\log(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon\sqrt{\pi_{min}}})}{\text{spectral gap}}$$

I have seen an simplified version of this as well:

$$t_{mix}(\varepsilon) \leq \frac{\log(1/\varepsilon\pi_{min})}{\text{spectral gap}}$$

Applying this to my problem, the Spectral gap = 1 - 0.98 = 0.02, π_min = 0.5 and choosing some small ε = 0.01

$$t_{mix}(0.01) \leq \frac{\log(1/(0.01 * 0.5))}{0.02} \approx 230.25$$
Thus, it would appear that approximately 230 transitions are needed to reach the target distribution of (0.5, 0.5) with an error of 0.01. Ideally, I should be able to repeat the simulation and observe this.
Have I correctly done this analysis?  And can someone please help understand why the second eigenvalue of the transition matrix is related to the time required to reach the stationary distribution - can this be mathematically proven?
Thank you

Note: I can provide the R code if anyone is interested


This is not exactly in line with your approach (Markov chains and mixing times), but it might be useful to gain some intuition.
First, notice that your initial question  ("How long will it take for this Markov Chain to reach its Stationary distribution?") is rather trivial: if the initial coin has uniform probability, then the chain is in the stationary distribution $(\frac 12 ,\frac 12 )$ for all $t$, regardless of $p$. To make it less trivial, one might assume that, say, $X_0 = 0$ (initial coin is head).
For any $t>0$, let $N=N(t) \in \{0, 1 \cdots t \}$ be the number of transitions in the Markov chain until time $t$. Then $X_t=0$ iff $N(t)$ is even. But $N$ follows a Binomial distribution with $B(t, q)$ with $q= 1-p = 0.01$. Then , for here:
$$P(X_t=0) = \frac{1}{2}(1+(1-2 q)^t) \tag 1$$
This tends to $1/2$ as expected. If $q$ is very small, and if we set $P(X_t=0) = \frac12 + \epsilon$ for some given $\epsilon >0$, then we need $$t = \frac{\beta}{-\log (1-2q)}\approx \frac{\beta}{2q} \hskip{1cm} \beta=-\log(2 \epsilon)$$
In particular, for $\epsilon = 0.01$ and $q=0.01$ this gives $t \approx 194$

Update: a different question, perhaps more interesting and more in the spirit in your original "Part 1" question, is about the running averages, i.e., how $S_t = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t X_i$ approaches $1/2$. Because "long term ratio of heads to tails" can be interpreted in in two ways: as fixing a (long) time $t$ and average, over many realizations, the values for that $t$ ; or as averaging over all the values up to $t$ over a single realization (see ensemble averages vs time averages). This is trickier. Assuming the first coin is random, it's clear that $E[S_t]=1/2$, but what about its variance?
For small $t$ ($t \ll 1/q$),  $S_t$ will behave almost as a fair Bernoulli variable, with variance $\sigma^2=1/4$
For large $t$, ($t \gg 1/q$). We'll have on about $t q$ runs, each corresponding (approximately) to a Geometric random variable, with $p=q$, $\mu=1/q$, $\sigma^2=(1-q)/q^2\approx 1/q^2$. Then $S_t$ will behave approximately as a gaussian with mean $1/2$ and variance $1/(2 t q)$. We can take a wild approximation guess:
$$\sigma^2_S \approx \frac{1}{2 qt +4}$$
Again, if we set a target standard deviation $\sigma_S = \epsilon$ we get $$t \approx \frac{1/\epsilon^2 -4}{2q} $$

@ Leonbloy: thank you so much! can you please help me with this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4965592/can-the-same-stochastic-process-have-2-different-likelihoods

I think you did this analysis correctly, some thoughts:

The study of mixing times is very interesting :) if you want are looking for a rigorous source, have a look at this book: Markov Chains and Mixing Times by Levin and Peres .
There Chapter 12 discusses the relationship between mixing times and spectral properties. In particular, they show the inequality (12.8)
$$Var_\pi (P^n f)\leq (\lambda_2)^{2n} Var_\pi(f),$$
where $\lambda_2$ is the second largest (in absolute value) eigenvalue. Changing from $L^2(\pi)$ to total variation distance gives you the $\pi_\min$ term. (Chapter 12 sounds like it is really complicated but it actually only depends on Chapters 1,2,4 where they define Markov chains and mixing.)

Speaking in terms of intuition, you know that the behaviour of a matrix (here $P$) is determined by its eigenvalues. If you restrict yourself to the subspace of an eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $P^nv =\lambda^n v$, this means there is exponential decay. When you now consider transition matrices you know that $\vert \lambda \vert \leq 1$ for all eigenvalues and that if the chain is aperiodic and irreducible then $1$ is the only eigenvalue with $\vert \lambda \vert =1$,  it has multiplicity $1$ and it corresponds to the stationary distribution. It is reasonable to think that the slowest exponential decay, i.e.\ the biggest lambda that isn't $1$, determines the mixing time and this is where $\lambda_2$ comes in.

Lastly: you sounded surprised that the stationary distribution is $(1/2,1/2)$. This can be seen easily because your experiment is symmetric in heads and tails. If you recolour your coin so that heads becomes tails and vice versa, the probabilities don't change but the asymptotic ratio flips. Therefore the asymptotic ratio must be invariant under flips, hence it is $1$ to $1$.


