Can the same Stochastic Process have 2 different Likelihoods?
This is a question I have been trying to understand for some time now.
Consider a simple First In First Out M/M/K queue (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue). This queue has the following properties:

$M$ :"memoryless" interarrival times. The time between arrivals of customers follows an exponential distribution.

$M$: "memoryless" service times. This means that the time it takes for a server to complete a service also follows an exponential distribution.

$k$ refers to the number of servers in the system.

Arrival Process: The arrivals of customers or jobs follow a Poisson process with a rate
$λ$

$λ$: This means the time between arrivals is exponentially distributed.

Service Process: Each of the $k$ servers provides service with an exponentially distributed service time. The service rate for each server is $$


I am trying to learn how to write the likelihood for the M/M/K queue. However, it seems that this can be done 2 different ways depending on what information we observe from the queue.
Method 1: Independent Likelihoods : We observe Arrival Process and Service Times
It seems to me that this approach is independent because:

Arrivals are determined by external factors (Poisson process)
Service times depend only on the server characteristics

Based on this, I tried to write the likelihood:

Arrival Process (observing $n$ arrivals in time $T$). This is basically a Poisson Process. For a Poisson Process in general, if we have (ordered) arrival times $\tau_1, \tau_2, \dots, \tau_n$, the likelihood can also be expressed as:

$$
\mathcal{L}(\lambda; \tau_1, \tau_2, \dots, \tau_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \lambda \exp(-\lambda \tau_i) = \lambda^n \exp\left(-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{n} \tau_i\right)
$$
Since $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \tau_i = T$, this simplifies to:
$$
\mathcal{L}(\lambda; t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n) = \lambda^n \exp(-\lambda T)
$$

Service Times (observing $m$ service times $s_1, s_2, ..., s_m$):


In an M/M/k queue, each server has an exponential service time distribution with rate μ
With k servers, the overall service rate is kμ
The probability density function for an exponential distribution with rate $kμ$ is $$ f(s) = k\mu e^{-k\mu s} $$

For $m$ independent service times, we multiply their individual densities
$$ L_S = \prod_{i=1}^m k\mu e^{-k\mu s_i} $$



Thus, we can optimize solve (numerically) both of these likelihood functions individually.
Method 2: Dependent Likelihoods We observe Interarrival Times and Departure Times
It seems to me that this approach will need a dependent (joint Likelihood) because:

Departures depend on both arrivals and service times
System state (queue length) affects the relationship between arrivals and departures

In this case, we can write:
For $n$ observed interarrival times ($A_1, ..., A_n$) and departure times ($D_1, ..., D_n$):
$$ L(A, D | \lambda, \mu) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(A_i, D_i | \lambda, \mu, Q_i) $$
Where:

$f(A_i, D_i | \lambda, \mu, Q_i)$ is the joint density function
$Q_i$ is the queue length immediately after the i-th arrival

Since we assume certain distributions (i.e. exponential) for a M/M/k queue, we can write:

Interarrival times are always exponentially distributed with rate $λ$:
$$ f_A(A_i) = \lambda e^{-\lambda A_i} $$

The distribution of the time until the next departure depends on the system state*:
a) If $Q_i < k$ (some servers are idle):
The next departure is exponentially distributed with rate $Q_i\mu$
$$ f_D(D_i | Q_i < k) = Q_i\mu e^{-Q_i\mu D_i} $$
b) If $Q_i \geq k$ (all servers are busy):
The next departure is exponentially distributed with rate $k\mu$
$$ f_D(D_i | Q_i \geq k) = k\mu e^{-k\mu D_i} $$

The joint density can then be written as:
$$ f(A_i, D_i | \lambda, \mu, Q_i) = \lambda e^{-\lambda A_i} \cdot \begin{cases} 
  Q_i\mu e^{-Q_i\mu D_i} & \text{if } Q_i < k \\
  k\mu e^{-k\mu D_i} & \text{if } Q_i \geq k
   \end{cases} $$

The full likelihood becomes:
$$ L(A, D | \lambda, \mu) = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda e^{-\lambda A_i} \cdot \begin{cases} 
  Q_i\mu e^{-Q_i\mu D_i} & \text{if } Q_i < k \\
  k\mu e^{-k\mu D_i} & \text{if } Q_i \geq k
   \end{cases} $$


Did I do this correctly? Can the same stochastic process (i.e. the M/M/K queue) have two separate likelihoods depending on what information we observe?
Thanks!

PS: Here are some additional justifications for the above Asterix*

Case 1: Some Servers are idle ($Q_i < k$)

When $Q_i < k$, only $Q_i$ servers are busy. The time until the next departure is the minimum of $Q_i$ independent exponential distributions, each with rate $μ$.
Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_Qi$ be the remaining service times for the $Q_i$ busy servers.
$$ X_j \sim \text{Exp}(\mu) \text{ for } j = 1, 2, ..., Q_i $$
The time until the next departure, $D_i$, is:
$$ D_i = \min(X_1, X_2, ..., X_{Q_i}) $$
For exponential distributions, the minimum of n independent Exp($λ$) random variables is Exp($nλ$). Therefore:
$$ D_i \sim \text{Exp}(Q_i\mu) $$
Thus, the probability density function for $D_i$ when $Q_i < k$ is:
$$ f_D(D_i | Q_i < k) = Q_i\mu e^{-Q_i\mu D_i} $$

Case 2: All Servers are Busy ($Q_i ≥ k$)

When $Q_i ≥ k$, all $k$ servers are busy. The time until the next departure is the minimum of $k$ independent exponential distributions, each with rate $μ$.
Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_k$ be the remaining service times for the $k$ busy servers.
$$ X_j \sim \text{Exp}(\mu) \text{ for } j = 1, 2, ..., k $$
The time until the next departure, $D+i$, is:
$$ D_i = \min(X_1, X_2, ..., X_k) $$
Again, using the property of the minimum of exponential distributions:
$$ D_i \sim \text{Exp}(k\mu) $$
Thus, the probability density function for Di when $Q_i ≥ k$ is:
$$ f_D(D_i | Q_i \geq k) = k\mu e^{-k\mu D_i} $$

Proof: I tried to write a simple math proof to demonstrate the above properties.

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be independent exponential random variables, each with rate $\lambda$. We want to prove that $Y = \min(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ is exponentially distributed with rate $n\lambda$.
The cumulative distribution function  of $Y$:
$$ P(Y > t) = P(\min(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) > t) $$
This is equivalent to all $X_i$ being greater than t:
$$ P(Y > t) = P(X_1 > t \text{ and } X_2 > t \text{ and } ... \text{ and } X_n > t) $$
Due to independence, this is the product of individual probabilities:
$$ P(Y > t) = P(X_1 > t) \cdot P(X_2 > t) \cdot ... \cdot P(X_n > t) $$
For an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$, $P(X > t) = e^{-\lambda t}$:
$$ P(Y > t) = e^{-\lambda t} \cdot e^{-\lambda t} \cdot ... \cdot e^{-\lambda t} = (e^{-\lambda t})^n = e^{-n\lambda t} $$
This is the complementary CDF of an exponential distribution with rate $n\lambda$.
Therefore, $Y \sim \text{Exp}(n\lambda)$.
